# UID and GID showing root

Tags: centos, users

We have a user account `foo` that somehow has been tied to root's uid, guid and groups.  when i run `id foo` it returns all the root id info.

`id foo`

`uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)`

This user account is for an old associate who is no longer here and i would like to remove their account completely from the server. 
Running `ps -ef | grep foo` doesn't return any process' for this user so i feel confident nothing is being ran under their username.

Running `userdel foo` indicates the user account doesn't exist as im sure it see's the account as root with the uid=0 but i still see the `foo` account it in `/etc/passwd` as `foo:x:0:0::/home/foo:/bin/bash`

What steps do i need to do to get rid of this account? Do i need to usermod and change the uid, gid and groups? Will that break anything if i pick a random uid not in use, i.e. uid=1099(foo)?

Im on CentOS 7, the server is connected to Active Directory, but this foo account is a Local account on the Linux serve. The user was terminated before we connected Linux to AD so the account no longer exists in Active Directory.

Comment: I would also probably check for unauthorized modifications to system files too, because it's really strange that `foo` *just happened* to be changed to UID=0/GID=0. This seems like a case of a [cuckoo's egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cuckoo%27s_Egg) to me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `vipw` to delete the line of the `foo` account in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`. Once you've done that, the account is technically gone.

Depending on `vipw` version, once you've used it to make changes to `/etc/passwd`, it may either prompt you: "do you want to edit `/etc/shadow` too? (Y/N)" or just suggest using `vipw -s` to edit `/etc/shadow`.

Many Linux distributions have the corresponding command `vigr` for editing `/etc/group` (and `/etc/gshadow`, if one exists).

Using `vipw` and `vigr` is safer than editing the files directly, as these commands will make a copy of the file before editing, and will make some sanity checks before replacing the original with the edited copy.

Once the account is deleted from `/etc/passwd`, you can do whatever you want to the user's home directory and local mail spool, i.e. `/home/foo` and `/var/mail/foo`. Usually, you'd want to just remove them unless there is some reason to archive them.

You'll also want to check the job scheduler; the layout may vary a bit, but at least on Debian systems, there are directories `atjobs`, `atspool` and `crontabs` in `/var/spool/cron/`: check for any mention of user `foo` in any of them, and remove any such files.

Comment: Thank you very much for the insight and those commands.  All three `vipw, vigr & vipw -s` is exactly what i was looking for. I was able to completely remove this user from the system now.  I also agree that setting a users account to be an "alias" of root, is not a good practice at all. Since we now manage users via Windows AD, this local account was pretty much a backdoor into the system.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend not to use tools like `userdel` as it is not clear why `foo` has uid `0` and you don't want to accidently delete root.

Rather edit `/etc/passwd` itself and delete the entry for `foo`. Make sure that root itself has a correct entry:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

Do the same for `/etc/group`. Delete entry for `foo` and check the entry for `root`:

```
root:x:0:
```

Then check password entry in `/etc/shadow`, delete `foo`, check `root` entry. Entry for `root` should look similar to:

```
root:SOMEPASSWORDCODE:17219:0:99999:7:::
```

Maybe there are additional entries for `foo` in `/etc/group`. Possible example:

```
audio:x:29:foo,pulse
```

For a clean job, remove `foo` respective `foo,` in those entries, too.

If `/home/foo` exists, check and delete it afterwards.

Currently `foo` is same as `root`. You won't find processes or files owned by foo as they all belong to `root`. File and process owners are registered by their uid, not by their name. So all processes or files with uid 0 appear as root. (Alternativly all root processes and files could appear as `foo` instead of `root`).

Comment: This answer is spot on, and raises a couple of interesting questions *why* you should not give a uid / gid 0 to "regular" users.

Comment: I'd rather say it's a good example of the reasons why not: it makes it  harder to remove the user account once it's no longer needed, and impossible to tell the user's files and processes apart from ones legitimately belonging to root.